# AutoHotKey :: Function Key not working properly

Tags: windows, autohotkey

**Solved**

Also check comments

I wrote a command in a script to emulate the function keys, to rename files easily(Windows F2 key helps renaming files.)

The script is pretty basic(I use multiple hotkey scripts instead of pasting all in one for more flexibility):

```
#l:: ; Windows Key + L 
F2
```

It just doesn't seem to work on the normal folders I want to change names of. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use:

```
#l::F2 ;for a simple one-to-one remap
```

or, alternatively:

```
#l::
Send {F2}
;insert more code here for a multiline command
return
```

Comment: I don't know for some strange reason the key mapping wasn't working. But yeah the send F2 works.

Comment: So does the first solution (one-to-one remap) not work, or were you referring to the code in the question itself? (please clarify, I am currently unsure about you are trying to say)

Comment: I meant that the first piece of solution, the one to one keymapping didn't work. The second snippet with send F2 worked. I don't know if it's a system concern since my device is a corporate one. But nevertheless the second piece of code works.

Comment: Just a heads up, if you are using a corporate laptop, they may flag AHK as potential malware. I don't know the specifics of your company's policy, but it might be worth asking your administration about this first to potentially avoid issues in the future. That's just my thoughts though, based on forum posts from 10+ years ago, so take it with a grain of salt I guess.

Comment: Yeah yeah, I did verify. Of course, one cannot take such risks. And thank you for the comment. Would request if someone else is reading, to take care of this.

Comment: The remapping syntax isn't going to work in this specific case due to the remapping syntax [internally using `{Blind}`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm#actually). You'd end up sending Windows+F2, which isn't desirable for your use. Normally typing in the send command works, because that will release the modifiers that are being held down for the duration of the send command. This can also be made a one-liner (`#l::SendInput, {F2}`) and [SendInput](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail) should/could be used instead of normal `Send`.